# Fancybox, how to skip element on clicking next or previous?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

I want to know if there is a method to skip en element from cycling(next,prev) without defining a class or a group.

A quick sample.

```
$('a').fancybox();
```

That would call fancy on each link. Now I want to skip certain link... so I am doing the following:

```
$('a.skip').unbind('click');
```

That works but the problem comes when we click next or previous, as you understand it will still display the element... So the question is: **how to skip certain element on clicking previous or next?**

I know the simplest way is to separate the group but I cant afford it... it can happen with lots of pages that require minimum hard coded changes. I am curious if there is a method to achieve that.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

what about `$('a:not(.skip)').fancybox();`

Comment: Someone said: "Simplicity is the root of all genius". That is a perfect example. Thank you.