# fancybox open a set of grouped images by external link

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I have a list of products with multiple images, each product has their own `rel="group123"` so that these are grouped.

My question is how can I link to this group from the product name?

[Example](http://www.equi-trek.com/uk/pre-owned)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just adding `rel="group123"` to your product name link would do the trick.

Comment: The problem with this is that it only works if I include a image URL in the href for product name. Second issue is that this will mean that the image the product name links to gets duplicated

Comment: try the suggestion from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6329993/fancybox-how-to-skip-element-on-clicking-next-or-previous

Comment: in other words just remove the href and modify fancybox to match on `a[href][rel=...]` css selector when initializing from a link

Comment: One more way: make the whole title plus images a single link and add the other images separately in a hidden div as demonstrated here http://jsfiddle.net/uZCC6/

Comment: assuming you have fancybox 2.1.0 you could modify the line `D.undelegate(selector, 'click.fb-start').delegate(selector + ":not('.fancybox-item, .fancybox-nav')", 'click.fb-start', run);` to add an exclusion rule for your item, or add one of the already excluded classes to the elements you want to ignore